# moving the source code from within swift playground to a swift file under "sources"

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift4, swift-playground

I have a SpriteKit scene in a swift playground (a SKView class with all the functions that come with it such as didMove, touchesBegan and Update), and when the live view is running it always responds super slow to touches and interactions. My question is would moving the whole source code from the swift playground to a separate swift file and import it into the "Sources" folder help with the live view response, and regardless of if it helps or not, how do I do it?

Here is what my swift playground looks like:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    //my source code 
  }

 let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 720, height: 540))
      if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
           scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
           sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
```

I also have about ten png and a couple .mp3 in the "Resources" folder, as well as Action.sks and GameScene.sks.

Comment: I find that Playgrounds suffer from various bugs & performance issues, especially when working with SpriteKit. Rather than playgrounds, I tend to create a new test project using the SpriteKit template. Far fewer issues this way.

Comment: @peacetype Yes, I eventually found out that moving the GameScene class into a separate swift file made it a lot faster since the live view would render everything at once instead of rendering the playground line by line. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a little earlier that when I move the GameScene class into a separate swift file everything would render very smoothly.